# Understanding Array sorting algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Looking for help describing this Algorithm for sorting an array. Is it a bubble or selection sort? Why do the elements switch?

```
#include <stdio.h>              //including stdio.h for printf and other functions
#include <conio.h>              //including conio.h for _getch() and other functions

int main()                        //default function for call
{
    int a[10] = { 2,4,6,8 };           //Array declaration size-10
    int n = 4;                                     //Temporary number for array size
    printf("\n\nArray Data : ");
    flushall();    //Printing message
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                     //Loop for displaying the data of array
    {
        printf(" %d ", a[i]);                   //Printing data
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                     //Loop for ascending ordering
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)             //Loop for comparing other values
        {
            if (a[j] > a[i])                //Comparing other array elements
            {
                int tmp = a[i];         //Using temporary variable for storing last value
                a[i] = a[j];            //replacing value
                a[j] = tmp;             //storing last value
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like an inefficient selection sort.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - Swapping multiple times per pass looks like bubble sort to me.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - I think it's an inefficient version of bubble sort.

Comment: @StephenNewell The bubble sort algorithm compares adjacent elements of an array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - Good point.

Comment: Fun fact: your program prints the array only *before* sorting, so an optimizing compiler could skip that part entirely: https://godbolt.org/g/g5SCWv

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score -1):

This is a less efficient way of bubble sort.

You can find explanations here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Step-by-step_example

A better code will be

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                {
                    // swap temp and arr[i]
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
```

It reduces number of comparisons and looping by optimizing the upper limit of loops.

You can see a video on this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmhjrI-aW5o&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: The algorithm in the question finds the maximum element in a sequence. But instead of one swapping it swaps each time when a current element is greater than the current maximum.